# Unity Tilemap, get each tile position, compare & delete all other tiles like this

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have an issue I cannot seem to wrap my head around how to go about it, i'm creating a game in Unity using Tilemaps (Grids).

**What I need**
the player clicks on a tile, check all tiles in the grid, find any tiles that have the same texture (or name, both can work) and remove all tiles that are the same as the one the player clicked EXCEPT the one the player clicked.

**What I've done**
So far, this code I've made literates through the tiles and successfully "Matches" the tiles that match the selected tile (though maybe this is not the best route). I manage to match by name but **I don't know how to get the position of that specific tile** (in this case 't') to than match it with the coordinates of of the current tile and delete the others.

here is my code

```
    void Start()
{
    grid = gameObject.GetComponent<Grid>();

    //Bounds is how big the tiles being used is
    bounds = new BoundsInt(baseTilemap.origin, baseTilemap.size);
    tilebaseArray = baseTilemap.GetTilesBlock(bounds);
    Debug.Log("Tilebase Array is " + tilebaseArray.Length + " tiles.");

}


void Update()
{
    Vector3 mouseWorldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    activeTileCoordinate = grid.WorldToCell(mouseWorldPos);

    Sprite activeTileSprite = baseTilemap.GetSprite(activeTileCoordinate);

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        try
        {
            Debug.Log("This is at position " + activeTileCoordinate);

            //put the sprite marker on this to know where play is on the second overlay
            overlayTilemap.SetTile(activeTileCoordinate, overlayTile);

            foreach (TileBase t in tilebaseArray)
            {
                if (t != null)
                {
                    //Debug.Log(t.name);

                    if (t.name == activeTileSprite.name)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Match");
                        //baseTilemap.SetTile(coordinate, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Debug.LogError(e);
        }

    }
```

Thank you for help everyone and hope I explained my problem best as possible. Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the solution I found for my application (game) in case anyone ever comes across this in the future:

```
                    foreach (var position in baseTilemap.cellBounds.allPositionsWithin)
                {
                    if (!baseTilemap.HasTile(position))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    else if(position == activeTileCoordinate)
                    {
                        Sprite otherTiles = baseTilemap.GetSprite(position);
                        Debug.Log("Active tile is at " + position + " and is " + otherTiles.name);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Sprite otherTile = baseTilemap.GetSprite(position);

                        if(otherTile.name == activeTileSprite.name)
                        {
                            baseTilemap.SetTile(position, null);
                        }

                    }
                }
```